# PostgreSQL: primary_key loses its sequence when a record is updated

Tags: java, postgresql

Tested:

- Postgres:13.1-alpine in Docker
- PostgreSQL 13 in Windows

and also

- H2 in-memory database.

I have a table, with 5 fields. The database is created automatically from spring. Here is my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String email;
```

for example: I want to update the address field:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXwLA.png)

The primary key `auto_increment` in postgres loses its sequence when executing an update, why? How can I prevent its sequence to remain.

The same update was done with H2 memory database and this change in the sequence of primary keys does not happen.

Has anyone else has similar issues?
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to prevent the sequence from going out of sync?

Comment: Don't post [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Having said that, your query is `select * from people`. Are you saying that you expect the query results to be ordered by `id`? If yes, then your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Good tipp about the image!
I'm just saying. Because, when updating a record in postgresql 13, the sequence of the primary key loses the order, but in H2 it doesn't. Sure I can do a >>select * people order by id asc;<< Do you have any idea, why this happens in postgres?

Comment: Each DBMS is free to implement the SQL standard as it sees fit and the standard states that query results are not ordered - unless the query contains an _order by_ clause so I repeat: Why do you assume that a [SQL] query - that does **not** have an _order by_ clause - should return the results ordered by ID? Or maybe I misunderstand what you mean when you say: _the primary key loses the order_. Perhaps you can explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It is assumed that, when you create a table with id auto_increment, every time you do an insert into, and do und `select * from table;` You find information that has been incremented in order 1,2,3,4. Now, when creating records, the ids are 1,2,3,4 because the ids are auto_increment, after doing an `update table set field=xyz where id=1;` now you put 2,3,4,1. I'm no Postgres expert, I just thought something needed to be changed, for example with `ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART` or something like that.

Comment: From the docs [Ordering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html): *After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on. A particular output ordering can only be guaranteed if the sort step is explicitly chosen.*

Comment: No `ORDER BY` means not ordered. The primary key is just to point to a unique record, it doesn't mean anything. And besides that, there is not even a requirement that every table must have primary key. It doesn't make sense to always order on the primary key when it doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: "...loses its sequence when executing an update..." -- Why do you care? Primary keys are internal identifiers that are not supposed to be good looking or sexy. If you are caring it means you want to show it or share it somewhere. That's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Why this happens**: update "breaks" your initial order because [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html) makes an update actually delete the old value and insert the new one elsewhere. You can inspect [hidden `ctid` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-CTID) to see the "location" before and after an update: [demo for entertainment](https://dbfiddle.uk/4LDZp6U_).
2. **Can you prevent it**: no. Or kind of pretend you do, if you [`alter table people set (fillfactor=10);`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) so that tuples are so sparse their pages always have headroom for the new values written by updates. This would bloat the table and reduce performance, and still *not really* guarantee any default order.

   You can also **"restore" that illusion of order** if you [`create index idx1 on people (id asc);`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) and then [`cluster people using idx1;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html), forcing it to be physically re-written in the order indicated by the index. Still, a query running an index-only scan on different index on this table can return values in the order of that other index, because it's not reading the table (heap) at all.
3. **Does anyone else have similar issues**: everyone, but few consider it an issue.
4. **Suggestions on how to prevent the sequence from going out of sync**: `id` is meant to *only identify* the row, and the incrementing part is a simple trick to keep it unique. If you want ordered results, I think the commenters already drove the point home: `order by` is required.

   Keep in mind that if you want the column to pull double duty as sorting position indicator, you'll complicate reordering things in it: since it primarily identifies the row, if you'd wish to move it up/down in the order, you'd also change its identity, and that'd have to cascade through all references to the row, everywhere, with [various effects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES). If something referenced it without a defined foreign key constraint to prevent or cascade the change, reordering would break that reference. If you plan things like that, it might be a good idea to instead define a separate `position`/`priority` column

Comment: "Does anyone else have similar issues?" -- This is a non-issue.

Comment: I would remove the section "Suggestions on how to prevent the sequence from going out of sync" since it doesn't add value.